# how can I use frames on phone gap and inappbrowser

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I doing a native app that is contains iframes an im also using inappbrowser, but im having a problem if I let

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
```

only the inappbroser works

and if I change the access origin to

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

only the iframes works

how can I use both??

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a little late, but you can add more than one access tag in the file. Just put them both in as separate lines.

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
<access origin="*"/>
```